# Is there any way of removing a defaultQuery

Tags: reactjs, searchkit

I've extended the `searchBox` component to provide amongst my own render function. I want to send a list of attributes of which the search-query should add negations on.

For example if I pass `'title', ['foo', 'bar']` as props to my searchBox component i want the search result to not include hits with title: foo or bar.

For this i'm using `addDefaultQuery` as following

```
this.context.searchkit.addDefaultQuery(query =>
  query.addQuery(BoolMustNot([{ match: { [attribute]: value } }])),
)
```

Is there any way of removing an added query once added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addDefaultQuery` isn't designed for this. Have a look at `setQueryProcessor` in docs http://docs.searchkit.co/stable/core/SearchkitManager.html

Comment: i am using next.js and i want to reload setQueryProcessor in dynamic route page ? how to do that?